# Laravel, how to call table name without hardcode by using same class model?

Tags: laravel, model

**The table name is MySQL I have like this**

```
energydata_1001
energydata_1002
energydata_1003
energydata_1004
energydata_1005
```

"energydata_prefix" is the id from another table
so the table name would be a lot in my database table depending on the user selection. the column table is the same.

this is my EnergyData model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class EnergyData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'energydata_';
}
```

this is my EnergyData Controller, how do I get table name like energydata_1001

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\EnergyData;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EnergyDataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $gettableID = 1001;

        return view('energydata.index',compact('energydata_1001'))
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add prefix on table actually?

Comment: yes, the table name is dynamic. when created from others

Comment: im not sure how, but 'energydata_' is fix.

Comment: so i can get the list when return, the user will input from the view page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you have to you can set a static variable on the model and use that to generate the table name:

```
class Something extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'energydata_';

    static $tableId = null;

    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table . static::$tableId;
    }

    public static function tableId($tableId = null)
    {
        if (is_null($tableId)) {
            return static::$tableId;
        }

        static::$tableId = $tableId;
    }
}


Something::tableId('1001');
```

This is possible but may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent models have a [`getTable`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getTable) function, so you can get the table for a model like this:

```
(new EnergyData())->getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically add prefix to the table name, you will need to use the Query Builder. Assign 'energydata_' to a variable and concatenate the prefix and call it using the query builder

```
public function index()
{
    $gettableID = 1001;

    $table_name = 'energydata_' . $gettableID;

    $users = DB::table($table_name)->get();
}
```

Comment: where is Query Builder location

Comment: what do you mean? if you're asking about importing Query Builder, insert this above your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`. You might want to read this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries